# Display Issue with real-estate listing results

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having a come and go issue with a PHP file that displays the web page for the real-estate listing details page. Part of the beginning description of the property shows up in between the address and price whi[ch is located above the image gallery display. The share icons that comes before the print icon one day is there and a few days later is not. I've looked at the HTML code and cant see what the problem is. Checked the divs opening and closing. Just find it strange its a come and go mostly not displaying properly. 
Screencap below:
[image: page below]

This is a WordPress site. I am using the Wp Residence 1.15.2 theme. The recommended theme is Enfold theme v3.5.4 ( I have tried using the current version as well) which is the theme the creators (Restpro) recommend to use and what they have written the different template php files in using that framework. But one day the gallery decided to not show up anymore using Enfold so this is why I am using the theme stated about that is giving the least amount of trouble to a certain extent.  Gallery mainly does not display on enfold it might for some odd reason for a short period of time.

I've viewed the page/ site on chrome (my primer browser), edge, internet explorer, and Firefox. The only difference in functionality between the browsers is that on internet explorer, and edge if you click on the main image you get a large popup box of that image which is what is wanted. 
The only edits I have made to the PHP file is adding the extra sections for pulling the data from the MLS and displaying info about the property (room dimensions, location info, schools etc.)

The development website is located [HERE](http://retspro.nohasslepropertysearch.net). Just click on advanced search to perform a random search.
example of listing details results: http://retspro4.nohasslepropertysearch.net/listing-details/listing-2143864-0/

Listing details php template. [Link to file here](https://files.mycloud.com/home.php?brand=webfiles&seuuid=48f8dc23404bab70e50842127388e0eb&name=listing_detail)

Appreciate any help in the matter. Have been working on this for several months with one issue after another with the plugin or theme/s and developer is not very responsive for the most part. Have tried 3 different versions of the plugin without one beginning fully functional or bug-free.

Answer (score 0):

Find `<div class="remarks" style="margin-bottom:10px;">` and change to `<div class="remarks" style="margin-bottom:10px;clear:both;">`

The HTML looks like a completely bloated mess but this resolved it for me.

Missing icons are not there because there is no anchor for them unlike the printer icon:

```
<div class="share-section-listing">

                <span class='st_sharethis' displayText=''></span>

                <span class='st_facebook' displayText=''></span>

                <span class='st_googleplus' displayText=''></span>

                <span class='st_twitter' displayText=''></span>

                <span class='st_pinterest' displayText=''></span>

                <span class='st_email' displayText=''></span>

                <span class="st_print"><a href="{link_printer_friendly_href}" rel="nofollow"> </a></span>

                <span class="st_fav"><a href="{adddel_favorite_href}" rel="nofollow"> </a></span>

            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Max Jones that worked. Any idea why the share icons do not display and only the printer icon shows up?

Comment: Edited answer to explain icons